# Thingsboard - Importing dashboards(and its components) from one env to other

Tags: thingsboard

How to import a dashboard from one server to other?

I tried and downloaded the  dashboard JSON file and imported it the other TB server, and gave the alias names.

But, the devices and the assets and other entities and its states did not get imported.

Am I doing it wrong?

Are the other devices and the assets and other entities , need to be imported seperately? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

when you import a dashboard you just import its configuration not the telemetries and attributes and value of them . try to import dashboard then see what entity it wants then go and define an entity for example define a device and use [thingsboard telemetry upload api](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/#telemetry-upload-api) to send needed telemetries to device and their value (try in postman). then go to dashboards edit mode and select your own entities sent before . for example : 
send a request to `http(s)://host:port/api/v1/$ACCESS_TOKEN/telemetry`
request body something like this :

```
{   "temperature": 456 ,
    "humidity" : 700 ,
    "energy" : 78444 ,
    "water" : 12344 ,
    "address" : "Iran, Tehran, 3 District"  
}
```